# jquery event listening, non-standard events

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to build a way for my selectors to 'listen' to 'global' events that are beyond the typical 'click' 'change' 'submit' etc. I've explored the various 'eventmanagers' that I could find, and they're all still designed for forms. Is there any way to do something like this for non-standard (i.e. custom) events? The goal is to have selectors subscribe to an event, and then be able to trigger it in **one** place and it will raise it for everything subscribed to it.

Inserting example for demonstration.

```
 return this.each(function () {
  $(this).live('ON_CONTENT_CHANGING', function (e) {
   $(this).block({
    overlayCSS: { opacity: 1, color: '#000' },
    timeout: 800
   });

   e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(this).live('ON_CONTENT_CHANGED', function (e) {
   $(this).sliding();
   $(this).unblock();

   e.preventDefault();
  });
```

// rest of plugin...

```
$("*").trigger('ON_CONTENT_CHANGING');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is built into jQuery, for example:

```
$(".button").bind("myEvent", function() {
  alert("myEvent fired on " + this.id);
});
```

Trigger by:

```
$("*").trigger("myEvent");
```

Or on a specific element (or any selector, like everything else jQuery):

```
$("#myButton").trigger("myEvent");
```

This uses [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).  As Jacob points out in comments, you can also bind with [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to custom events in 1.4+, like this:

```
$(".button").live("myEvent", function() {
  alert("myEvent fired on " + this.id);
});
```

Comment: In addition, if you use "live()" instead of "bind()" you can bind to a selector and new elements that match the selector will be subscribed for that event, even if they didn't exist when you set up the binding.

Comment: @JacobM:: However, keep in mind that live prior to 1.4 was limited to click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup.  Source: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I have read somewhere that the "*" selector is pretty bad to use, is there any truth to that? Won't this propogate to every item in the DOM?

Comment: Hrnm. This doesn't seem to work with live() even on jquery 1.4 for me.

Comment: @Stacey - Have a link to the non-working example?  And yes, `"*"` goes to every DOM object, you can restrict it down to things you know are bound, classes, inputs, whatever that may be.

Comment: Yeah, I've posted my code that doesn't work. The binding is done inside of the plugin.

Comment: @Stacey - If you're using `"*"` I wouldn't use `.live()` in that case you need to trigger it for a specific selector, like on a class, otherwise it'll bubble and fire many, many times.

Comment: Hrnm... That takes me back to square one.. Thanks for all of the information. This helps a lot with a lot of things.

Comment: @Stacey - If you have `$(this)` just use `.bind()` instead of `.live()`, `.live()` listens for a selector...but with `$(this)` you already have the element, just `.bind()` right to it, then `'$('*').trigger()` is an option.

Comment: @OMG Unicorns: In jquery 1.3.x live() could bind to the events you mention *plus custom events*, so it would work for this issue even in 1.3.